# State changed from starting to crashed can not find express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am using Heroku as a server but after deploying app does not run

> Error: Cannot find module './lib/express'    at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>
> at Object. (/app/node_modules/express/index.js:11:18)
>
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad
>
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)

Comment: it runs locally perfect

Comment: Check your `package.json` file

Comment: I have checked it finally  solved it by not checking packge.json but I have removed node modules and installed all modules one by one so it's up now @SourabhSomani

Comment: What do you mean by "installed all modules one by one"? Are you doing this interactively via `heroku run bash` or something? That doesn't do what you think it does on Heroku. Your dependencies _must_ be properly defined in `package.json` and a lock file.

Comment: don't know but what i have done is removed all node modules and then installed modules one by one locally and pushed to the heroku and that works fine which was not working with simple npm install command @Chris

Comment: Again, what does "one by one" _mean_? Specifically, how did you do that? It looks like your problem has disappeared?

Comment: Unless you set your Heroku app up so that they can examine your package.json and download the node_modules themselves, your app will likely stop working next time the dyno automatically restarts. You should aim for a working automated configuration. Try comparing your app to their Node.js sample app to see if there's a difference in how it's setup. https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample